# Best way to partition file creation by a max size

Tags: c#, architecture, limit

I'm creating files that have a certain structure to them.  They begin with a `Header`, then contain a block of `DataElement`s.  (The exact details don't matter to this question.)

I have a `DataFileWriter` connected to a `FileStream` for output.  The problem is, the service that's consuming the files I'm building will reject any data file whose size is larger than the arbitrary value `TOOBIG`.

Given these constraints:

- Every file must start with a `Header`
- Every file must contain one or more `DataElement`s, which must be written out completely; a file ending with an incomplete `DataElement` is invalid
- It is perfectly valid to stop at the end of the current element and begin writing a new file with a new header, as long as each `DataElement` is written exactly once
- The `DataFileWriter` doesn't and should not know that it's writing to a `FileStream` as opposed to some other type of stream; all it knows is that it has a `Stream` and in other cases that could be a completely different setup.
- `DataElement` does not have a fixed size, but it's reasonable to assume any given element won't exceed 4 KB in size.

What's the best way to set up a system that will ensure, assuming that no massive `DataElement`s come through, that no file exceeding a size of `TOOBIG` will be created?  Basic architecture is given below; how would I need to modify it?

```
public class DataFileWriter : IDisposable
{
   private readonly Stream _output;
   private readonly IEnumerable<DataElement> _input;

   private const int TOOBIG = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 GB

   public DataFileWriter(IEnumerable<DataElement> input, Stream output)
   {
      _input = input;
      _output = output;
   }

   public void Write()
   {
      WriteHeader(); // writes the header to _output
      foreach (var element in input)
      {
         WriteElement(element); // serializes the record to _output
      }
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      _output.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not an architecture question. Nor is there a best practice. LINQ for example introduced a [Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) to partition items based on count. MoreLINQ offered a similar method for years. The BatchBlock in the TPL DataFlow library does the same. Chunking/partitioning by item count is possibly the easiest way, especially if items are less than 4KB.

Comment: You can also build a method that keeps count of the files it writes until it reaches a limit, closes the stream and then creates a new one. That's used in rolling file log providers like Serilog's [Rolling File Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/tree/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Chunking by count won't work because the element size is not fixed.  Records won't be larger than 4 KB but they could be a lot smaller, and I'd prefer to keep the number of files created to a minimum.

Comment: In that case you'll have to count the number of written bytes before closing. The `Stream` implementation matters here. With a `FileStream` you could just check the `Position` to see whether' you're close to the limit. Otherwise you may have to calculate the size of the element before writing it to ensure it won't exceed the limit. The question is a bit vague and there *are* similar questions. Serilog uses a [WriteCountingStream](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/WriteCountingStream.cs) wrapper to count bytes written

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And now you're running afoul of one of the constraints: the writer should not know the specific type of stream it's connected to, because this problem is situational rather than universal.  This is why this is an architecture question: all of the obvious, trivial answers are wrong.

Comment: The WriteCountingStream wrapper takes care of that. It increases the count each time `Write` is called, which always knows how many bytes it needs to write. Check it and the [FileSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs) that uses it. This case is not that different from a rolling log.

Comment: In the FileSink, [EmitOrOverflow](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs#L103) checks whether it can write to the WriteCountingStream or returns false.  It *doesn't* try to create a new file though, that's left to the [RollingFileSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/RollingFileSink.cs), which also emits header. The significant architecture design here is that the concerns are split along several classes. The Counting wrapper only counts. The FileSink only writes up to a limit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting.  I'll look at that a bit closer and see if I can adapt it to my use case.  The tricky thing here is, the counting stream might not necessarily be connected directly to the serializer either; it's perfectly valid to have other streams in between, such as a compressor.

Comment: Are you writing each element using `StreamWriter.WriteLine`, or do you have another framing mechanism?